# Show a textbox on drop down select

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, onclick, onchange

I tried doing onchange and onclick event and I'm having trouble with both of them. When executing my code, Firebug tells me my showTextBox function is not defined.

When the value 1 is selected for the State dropdown, I need to display the `<div>` which holds a textbox. I'm moved the onclick attribute in the option tags as well as tried onchange attribute and still get showTextBox() is not defined in Firebug.

```
<select id="AddrType" onclick="showTextBox();"
        height="30px" style="width: 90px"> 
  <option value="10"></option>
  <option value="0">City</option>
  <option value="1">State</option>
  <option value="2">Zip</option>
</select>   

 <br />

 <div id="stateText" style="visibility: hidden">
   State <input type="text" id="STATE"/>
 </div>
```

Here is the function that called when either the onclick or onchange events are triggered:

```
function showTextBox() {
    console.log("in check Drop down");
    if ($('#AddrType').val() == 'State') {
        $('#stateText').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    console.log($('#AddrType').val());
```

Any help with this. I've Googled it, but I can't seem to find something that works. I can't use the `document.getElementById()` function.

Comment: I presume in your code you have a closing } for showTextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#AddrType').change(function(){
           if ($(this).val() == '1') {
               $('#stateText').css({'display':'block'});           
           }
        });
  });


</script>
```

and update your select to this:

```
   <select id="AddrType" height="30px" style="width: 90px"> 
     <option value="10"></option>
     <option value="0">City</option>
     <option value="1">State</option>
     <option value="2">Zip</option>
  </select>
```

also, this works perfectly fine.

```
   <select id="AddrType"  onchange="showTextBox()" height="30px" style="width: 90px"> 
      <option value="10"></option>
      <option value="0">City</option>
      <option value="1">State</option>
      <option value="2">Zip</option>
  </select>
```

and where showTextBox() is:

```
   function showTextBox(){
        if ($('#AddrType').val() == '1') {
                   $('#stateText').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    }
```

Comment: theirs no onclick or onchange event in this on change it alerts what the value is..?

Comment: yeah..because m binding change event of the dropdown at the runtime. I've updated my answer..it does exactly what you are trying to do in your code.

Comment: This is gettign closer as its in the change function. I get style is undefined error. is style="visibility: hidden" valid on a div?

Comment: ohh my god, there is no such thing 'style' for jquery object. I've updated my answer.see it now

Comment: for some reason it does not like onchange attribute it tells me function is undefined but it is clearly in my document.ready. I got it to work with your first suggestion but with .css({'visibility':'visible'});    thanks for your help!

Comment: define functions outside document.ready and in the head section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `val()` is probably returning `"1"` instead of `"State"` you're checking against.

Not only on jQuery but also when you POST the form data to a server, the value of `AddrType` will be the `value` attribute of the chosen `option` element ("City / State / Zip" in your case is just the 'caption' of the value).

Comment: Yes I understand that but for some reason Firebug is telling me the function is not defined.

Comment: in the select the onclick="showTextBox();" when that is called in Firebug it says showTextbox is not defined.

Comment: It could be that you have a syntax error somewhere in the code above the function definition that prevent FireFox from parsing your function.

Try to enter `showTextBox` in FireBug console to see if it's defined.